# Синонимизировать [dragndrop] и [draganddrop]

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, статус-завершено, синонимы-меток

Есть идентичные метки [dragndrop](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dragndrop) и [draganddrop](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/draganddrop).

Пытался создать метку [drag-and-drop](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drag-and-drop), так как не люблю слова слитно:

[image: попытка создания метки drag-and-drop]

> Вы пытаетесь создать метку [drag-and-drop](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drag-and-drop), хотя уже существует метка [draganddrop](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/draganddrop)! Если вы всё равно считаете, что новая метка необходима, заведите обсуждение на [Мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com)

Кстати, [drag-and-drop](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drag-and-drop) — это основная метка на enSO.
Если это совсем сложно, то, в крайнем случае, предлагаю основной сделать [draganddrop](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/draganddrop).

Comment: Запилите ответами по каждому варианту. Голосованием и определим.

Comment: @Suvitruf Мне кажется, что [drag-and-drop], что [drag-n-drop], 100% будут лучше, чем то, что сейчас. Поэтому если кто-то готов из модераторов сделать, то может сделать на своё усмотрение.

Comment: Синонимизировал к [tag:drag-n-drop].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Хм. Мне вообще ближе `drag'n'drop`, но такой [тег не создать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drag'n'drop). Оно будет распознаваться как `dragndrop`.

Из текущих вариантов я лично за [drag-and-drop](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drag-and-drop) или, как подсказал alexolut, за [drag-n-drop](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drag-n-drop). По поводу того, что её нельзя создать, думаю, модераторы могут это поправить. А если нет, то можно сначала выпилить [draganddrop](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/draganddrop), а потом навесить [drag-and-drop](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drag-and-drop) на вопросы.

Comment: Может [tag:drag-n-drop]?

Comment: @alexolut хм, да, этот вариант даже больше нравится.

Comment: @alexolut Да это 100% лучше, чем слитно [tag:dragndrop]. Хороший и привычный вариант.

Comment: @Kromster синонимизировал к [tag:drag-n-drop].

Answer (score -1):

Есть вполне осмысленный русскоязычный аналог: [перетаскивание](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5). Именно такой перевод [использует Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/language/Search?&searchTerm=drag%20and%20drop&langID=Russian&Source=true&productid=All%20Products).

Правда, настолько "популярный", что на ruSO до сих пор нет соответствующей метки. Но в отношении **переводов** (в противоположность англицизмам) это не редкость.

Часто употребляемое "drag & drop" можно упомянуть в кратком описании метки, чтобы уж точно ни у кого не возникло сомнений.

Comment: Не согласен, drag-and-drop — название вполне особенное, самодостаточное, встречающееся в литературе https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag-and-drop По поводу термина "перетаскивание" сильно не уверен.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov ...но там же нет ни одной ссылки на литературу. Там вообще ни одной ссылки на источники нет, о чём есть предупреждающая плашка :D А в переводах технической литературы на русский язык зачастую не парятся с переводом терминов, оставляя как есть или используя англицизмы. Распространённый подход, но лучший ли?

Comment: Ну может быть. Просто это скорей экзотика, которая лично мне режет слух (это субъективно, согласен). Но как только будет более-менее популярен термин или метка, то можем объединить в вашу сторону.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/824206/15479 Это из той же повести как и "вытаскивающий запрос"? :D

Comment: @Suvitruf в отличие от "вытаскивающего запроса", "перетаскивание" таки встречается, и не абы где :) Добавил ссылку.

Comment: @D-side я такое только в школьные времена видел в методичках из начала 2000-х по Делфям (:

Comment: @Suvitruf почти уверен, что вы просто мало пользуетесь переведённым на русский язык софтом :)

Comment: @D-side я всё стараюсь на английском. Так и с документации проще )

Comment: @Suvitruf ну вот вам и ответ, почему для вас английский вариант привычнее :)

Comment: @Suvitruf в голосину с вытаскивающего запроса.